# Magento 2.1 - Load Product in External Script

Tags: magento-2.1, external

I'm porting over a little web service developed by a previous developer that pulled **product data** from an older Magento 1.9 install and spits it out as a **json response**.

They bootstrapped Magento 1.9 with this:

```
$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
\Mage::app('default');
```

And they loaded product data with:

```
$productHelper = \Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product       = $productHelper->load($product_id);
```

With Magento 2.1 I'm bootstrapping with:

```
require getenv('MAGENTO_PATH') . 'app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('MagentoApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
return $app->getObjectManager();
```

Here's the MagentoApp code:

```
class MagentoApp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{
    protected $objectManager;

    public function launch()
    {
        $this->_state->setAreaCode('frontend');
        return $this->_response;
    }

    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->_objectManager;
    }
}
```

When I go to get the Magento Product in the little web service's product model, I'm using

```
$objectManager = $app->getObjectManager();

$product = $objectManager
        ->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')
        ->getById($product_id);
```

and getting the error `Call to a member function get() on null` (referring to the `$objectManager` as null) . What's weird is if I `exit(var_dump($product->getData())` after that method call, I get the actual product data just fine.

If anyone could shed any light on this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with this (ignore weird static stuff, I didn't have time to rework that class)

> ProductModel.php

```
...
public static function getDataByID($product_id)
{
    Config::boostrap();
    Config::setProductId($product_id);
    return Config::run();
}
```

> Config.php

```
    public static function boostrap()
    {
        if (!self::$enviroment_loaded) {
            require getenv('MAGENTO_PATH') . 'app/bootstrap.php';
            self::$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
            self::$app = self::$bootstrap->createApplication('MagentoApp');
        }
    }

    public static function run()
    {
        if (!self::$enviroment_loaded) {
            self::$bootstrap->run(self::$app);
            self::$enviroment_loaded = true;
        }

        return self::$app->getProductById();
    }

    public static function setProductId($id)
    {
        self::$app->setProductId($id);
    }
```

> MagentoApp.php

```
class MagentoApp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{
    protected $productId;

    public function launch()
    {
        $this->_state->setAreaCode('frontend');
        return $this->_response;
    }

    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getProductById($id = null)
    {
        if (!$id) {
            $id = $this->getProductId();
        }

        $product = $this->_objectManager
            ->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')
            ->getById($id);

        $store = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
        $imageUrl = $store
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) .
                'catalog/product' .
                $product->getImage();

        return [
            'productID'   => $id,
            'productName' => $product->getName(),
            'link'        => $product->getProductUrl(),
            'image'       => $imageUrl
        ];
    }
```